# PHP How to also check if active

Tags: php, session, pdo, login-script

I have a problem with my code. Or rather don't know how to implement what I would like to have.
I would like; Also in this code, check if the username have a 1 in active column. and if so the proceed to login protected page else return to login page.

> ```
> <?php
>
> session_start(); 
>
> function validateUser(){
>
> session_regenerate_id (); 
> $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
> $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
>
> }
> $username = $_POST['username'];
> $password = > $_POST['password'];
> require('config.inc.php'); 
> $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass); 
> $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT password_hash FROM users WHERE username =:username");
> $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR,32);
> $stmt->execute(); $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
> $db=null;
> $dbhash = $result['password_hash'];
>
> if ($dbhash == crypt($password, $dbhash)){
> validateUser();    
> header('Location: ../main.php');
> }else{
> header('Location: ../index.php?invalidcreds=1');
> die();
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

So what you guys think? I have tried everything but can't get it to work.

Also I would like to have a admin column no/0 or yes/1 so I can protect certain links or text in my page. But first thing first.

Comment: why not select 'active' in your cirrent querry

Comment: Why is there a `>` when initializing `$password` ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: Thanks for the #1 implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `is_active` column in your db then use:

`SELECT is_active, password_hash FROM users where username=:username`

In your php just use:

```
if($result['is_active'])
{
    //Send to restricted login
}
else
{
    //Send to normal login
}
```

Also, like I said in a comment, you have a stray `>` when you initialize your password variable. It may be a reason why your code isn't working.

Comment: the > is just an typo :)

Comment: Thanks, WOW so simple and yet I not see. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is the code and it work perfect. And the > was just a typo sorry. Thanks Bun for your super easy code.

Does this look okay? Or just plain wrong. I'm a bit unsure of the if code or is this the way to go!?

```
<?php

session_start();
function validateUser(){
    session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
require('config.inc.php');
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT active, password_hash FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 32);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$db =null;

if($result['active']){
    $dbhash = $result['password_hash'];
if ($dbhash == crypt($password, $dbhash))
    validateUser();
    header('Location: ../main.php');
}
else{
    header('Location: ../index.php?invalidcreds=1');
    die();
}

?>
```

But now if I would like to do a admin column too and try to implement this here, how would I do this? I know there needs to be added perhaps a bit more code in other places also. Nothing pretty or advanced. It's just a simple login so. Any advice where I should direct my eyes at, private/public classes (I've tried this but I got lost in the code totaly)

Comment: By admin column I mean from the first post and bottom text. an easy way to check perhaps in sessions if admin = 1 then protect links/text/codes in protected page.